# LinkedIn Post URL in Comment using API

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, api, linkedin-api

In my iPad application, I want to post a URL in LinkedIn .

Right now , I am using these API's:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares with reference to [Docs](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api)

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];

OAMutableURLRequest *request =
[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                consumer:_oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                   token:_oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                callback:nil
                       signatureProvider:nil];

    NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [[NSDictionary alloc]
                         initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"anyone",@"code",nil] , @"visibility",
                        @"www.google.com", @"comment", nil];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];

[request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:)];
```

The above code works and I can post this www.google.com in LinkedIn.

But , by replacing this url to:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/now-next/id724323924?ls=1&mt=8

It give success response code from api. But , I cannot see any post containing this url in the LinkedIn.

Any help will be appreciated.
Please guys join hands..

Comment: You may need to replace & with &amp; or %26

Comment: @gWiz Thanks for response but I tried no change.

Comment: I solved it using URL shortener.But, it was not a accurate solution.

Comment: I have same issue .. i got success in response but there in no post on linkedin